# Latitude and Longitude to Vector3 Not Aligning on 3D Sphere

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vector, coordinates

I am trying to convert latitude and longitude to a Vector3 format. For a given latitude and longitude, I want to convert it into a Vector3, where a marker object will be positioned at this Vector3 location.

Here is my code:

```
void createLand()
{
    double latitude_rad = (latitude) * Math.PI / 180;
    double longitude_rad = (longitude) * Math.PI / 180;

    double xPos = (radiusEarth * Math.Cos((latitude_rad)) * Math.Cos((longitude_rad)));
    double yPos = (radiusEarth * Math.Cos((latitude_rad)) * Math.Sin((longitude_rad)));
    double zPos = (radiusEarth * Math.Sin((latitude_rad)));

    markerPos.x = (float)xPos;
    markerPos.y = (float)yPos;
    markerPos.z = (float)zPos;

    ObjectMarker.position = markerPos;
}
```

I am using 6371 as radiusEarth, Here is the output for London lat:51.509865, lon:-0.118092:

[image: Output for London Coordinates]

And here is the output for the North Pole, lat:90, lon:135:

[image: Output for North Pole Coordinates]

The marker (which is the small shiny sphere) is in the wrong position.

Is there anything wrong with my conversion or is there any other way to fix this?

EDIT...

Earth texture that I have used can be found [here](http://planetpixelemporium.com/earth8081.html), it is the 10K image. I built the sphere and applied the texture using Blender - I applied a rotation to the sphere so that the front view will reflect the position of lat,long: 0,0.

Code to create the Earth object:

```
void createEarth()
{
    ObjectEarth.gameObject.transform.localScale = 1f * radiusEarth * Vector3.one;
}
```

EDIT 2...

This is where the marker is placed when using Unity's predefined vectors:

```
void createLand()
{
    ObjectMarker.position = radiusEarth * Vector3.forward;
}
```

[image]

```
void createLand()
{
    ObjectMarker.position = radiusEarth * Vector3.right;
}
```

[image]

```
void createLand()
{
    ObjectMarker.position = radiusEarth * Vector3.up;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Its almost like the sphere underneath is out by 90 in both directions.. as picture was aligned with the north pole spot, I think London would be in the right place..

Comment: Your math seems right, what was the orientation of your sphere and camera/inspector view when you took those screenshots?

Comment: Please include the texture you are using and code that will create the sphere and apply the texture to it to make a [mre].

Comment: @NSJacob1 - the Earth sphere doesn't have any rotation applied to it. Inspector was set to front view when the screenshots above were taken

Comment: @Ruzihm - I have created an edit explaining how the sphere is created and how the texture has been applied.

Comment: @BugFinder, Are you saying that I should subtract 90 degrees from both the latitude and longitude?

Comment: Not necessarily. Just that looking at the images it just seemed 90 degrees ish off

Comment: @SidS  I'm interested in looking at how this project has developed, as I'm trying to do something similar.

Comment: @IlludiumPu36 you can check out the github repository of this project, [here.](https://github.com/SidSidSid16/StarMapLite). I used the Hipparcos star catalogue from [here.](https://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/) From that website, you can simply download the dataset. Check out the code from my repo. I am taking a break from this project, contact me if you need more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong axes for your conversion to 3d space.

- Y is the up/down axis, so that should definitely be the one that is `sin(latitude)`.
- 0,0 is at `z = 1*radiusEarth`, so z needs to be the one with cos*cos.
- 0,90 is at `x = -1 * radiusEarth`, so x needs to be negative cos*sin.

Altogether:

```
void createLand()
{
    double latitude_rad = latitude * Math.PI / 180;
    double longitude_rad = longitude * Math.PI / 180;

    double zPos = radiusEarth * Math.Cos(latitude_rad) * Math.Cos(longitude_rad);
    double xPos = -radiusEarth * Math.Cos(latitude_rad) * Math.Sin(longitude_rad);
    double yPos = radiusEarth * Math.Sin(latitude_rad);

    markerPos.x = (float)xPos;
    markerPos.y = (float)yPos;
    markerPos.z = (float)zPos;

    ObjectMarker.position = markerPos;
}
```

Comment: @SidS I updated the answer based on the images shown in the question. Note the negative in `double xPos = -radiusEarth * Math.Cos(latitude_rad) * Math.Sin(longitude_rad);` and the matching  `markerPos.x = (float)xPos;`,
   `markerPos.y = (float)yPos;`, and 
    `markerPos.z = (float)zPos;`

Comment: Just tried the code above, using lat, long, 90, 135, the marker lines up with the North Pole as intended, although when using 0,0 the marker goes to the origin point, which is at the centre, inside of the Earth sphere

Comment: @SidS That's really weird, because `double zPos = radiusEarth * Math.Cos(latitude_rad) * Math.Cos(longitude_rad);` should be `zPos = radiusEarth;`... so it shouldn't be inside the earth, right? Seems like there's another typo I'm overlooking or a mistake in copying it to your script.

Comment: I've just copied and pasted the code, and yes, it should be inside of the Earth. I'll go over my script to make sure there's nothing wrong on my end.

Comment: @SidS Sorry about the notification spam. The calculations work out as shown [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4Teyon). Make sure you are really assigning `markerPos.z = (float)zPos;`

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to diagnose the z vector. Will post updates once fixed.

Comment: The new code in the answer is correct, the problems were on my end. Thank you!